# Is this differential equation exact? $(2x+4y)+(2x-2y)*y' = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(2x+4y)+(2x-2y)y' = 0$$
$$(2x+4y)dx+(2x-2y)dy = 0$$

$\dfrac {\partial }{\partial y}M(x,y) = 4$
And
$\dfrac {\partial }{\partial x}N(x,y) = 2$

$\partial_x N(x,y)$ and $\partial_y M(x,y)$ doesn't equal, so i do this i use integration factor:

$μ(x) = e^{2/(2x-2y)} \, dx $

but after

$μ(2x+4y)+μ(2x-2y)*y' = 0$ my equation doesn't be a  exact equation.

Comment: Your notation is slightly off... For example $M(x,y)dy/dx$ (similarly for $N$) should instead be $M(x,y) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ where $F(x,y) = (\dots)dx + (\dots)dy= 0$ is your entire function.  Furthermore, why the integrating factor? That is a tool used in a different method.

Answer (score 1):

$$(2x+4y)dx+(2x-2y)dy = 0$$
$$(x+2y)dx+(x-y)dy = 0$$
Is not an exact DE as you noticed. It's homogeneous $y=tx$:
$$(1+2t)dx+(1-t)(xdt+tdx )= 0$$
$$\dfrac {dx}{x}+\dfrac {1-t}{1+3t}dt=0$$
Now it's an exact DE.